# Change out column of data using drop down

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

I'm looking to change out a column of data in my excel spreadsheet with 8760 data points without copy and paste. I'd like to use a drop down menu to select various data set columns in other tabs of the workbook which will auto populate the column. How might I go about this?

Comment: I'd say that either you have a macro that populate the column, as a function can't change any cells other than itself, or you fill your column with a function that takes the value from the set, based on cell position and value chosen in drop down. If you provide an example on how the dat ais structured, I could provide an example on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give specifics without examples, but here is one way to do it.
Say that this is your data on `sheet2`:
[image: Example database]

And so on.

Then on sheet1 you have a data validation list where you can choose the different lists: 
[image]

Then you can fill the range you want to populate with a function to search and retrieve the right value.
There are are a few ways to do this. You could do a very controlled nested if like this:

```
=IF(Sheet1!$C$2=Sheet2!$C$2,Sheet2!C3,IF(Sheet1!$C$2=Sheet2!$D$2,Sheet2!D3,IF(Sheet1!$C$2=Sheet2!$E$2,Sheet2!E3,"")))
```

For the first cell, and then copy down. But this is not a very graceful or dynamic way of making it work.

A different approach would be using the classic index match approach:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!3:3,MATCH($C$2,Sheet2!$2:$2)),"")
```

For the first row, and then copy down.
`MATCH` searches row 2 in sheet2 for anything matching the drop-down list (*here in `C2`*), and returns the column number.
`INDEX` then returns the value of the cell in the specified row (3 being the first row in my example) and column returned by the `MATCH` function.
`IFERROR` makes sure that the cell is empty, should the drop down box be empty.

This then looks something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create your own drop-down list for some cell, do the following:

```
1.    Enter the list of items in a range.
2.    Select the cell that will contain the drop-down list.
3.    On the Data tab, in the Data Tools group, click Data Validation
4.    In the Data Validation dialog box, on the Settings tab
      In the Allow drop-down list, select List.
      In the Source box, specify the range that contains the items (ex: =$A$1:$A$3).
      Make sure that the In-Cell Dropdown option is checked.
5.    Click OK.
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question. I'm able to create a drop down of random variables but how can I go about auto-filling the 8760 data points in the column below (the reason for creating the drop down)?